# Was Atticus's name meant to mean anything?

Tags: symbolism, name-significance, harper-lee, to-kill-a-mockingbird

I am currently studying Latin, and somewhere I read about a man named [Titus Pompons Atticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Pomponius_Atticus), and as a lover of literature, I do not like to assume that it is just a coincidence that Atticus Finch of *To Kill a Mockingbird* has the same name.

**Was there anything special or meaningful to Atticus's (first) name in *To Kill a Mockingbird*?**

*note: Please do not limit your answer to only the person I found, if there is a better example, by all means use it.

Comment: I have (fx: gasps) never read TKAM, but I remark that "Atticus" approximately means "Greek" (more specifically, it means "from the region of Greece near Athens"). If the name has significance, I'd guess it's more likely to be as a pointer to classical Greece than as an echo of some specific Roman with that name. But it's no more than a guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [analysis website](http://theconversation.com/whats-in-a-name-atticus-finch-and-his-roman-forebears-44911) claims that:

> In Latin, Atticus is an adjective meaning “belonging to Attica”, the region in which Athens is located, or more simply, “Athenian”. As a name, it had connotations of **literary sophistication and culture**.

...

> Atticus was a **suave and charming** wheeler-dealer who deliberately eschewed political office.
>
> He preferred to exert **influence** through his business interests and by cultivating **powerful friendships**.

...

> Although rare in the Republican period, the name Atticus became much more common under the Roman empire. The evidence of epitaphs and other inscriptions shows that it was held by **senators**, centurions, cavalrymen, **town** **councillors**, freedmen and soldiers in the praetorian guard.
>
> But it did not lose its association with Greek **culture and refinement**. One of the most famous Attici was Herodes Atticus, an extremely wealthy **intellectual** and **orator** who was appointed as tutor in Greek rhetoric to the future emperor Marcus Aurelius.

This [source](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/why-did-harper-lee-chose-certain-names-for-certain-10705) states:

> Atticus' name is a nod to the Roman orator known for his **just decisions**.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atticus) states that it is an "adjective Latin name meaning '**classic**, **elegant**'".

*(emphasis mine on all of the quotes above)*

In essence, the bolded words represent Atticus' character very well. He is a sophisticated, highly educated, and well-cultured intellectual who always attempts to make the most ethically right decision in any situation. His name was carried by powerful Roman orators, senators, and councillors, and his occupation as a charismatic lawyer reflects this. Lee chose this name because of its historical connotation of class, elegance, sophistication, and intellectualism, all qualities that embody Atticus Finch.